# has_and_belongs_to_many where both models have underscore names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many, tablename

I'm working with Rails 3.2.1 and have the two models CookingVenue and DiningVenue with associated MySQL tables of cooking_venues and dining_venues.  I have set up the has and belongs to many relationship between the two models but what's the name of the MySQL table name here to represent the join?

Is it `cooking_venues_dining_venues`?

Will Rails try to find habtm relationships between cooking and venues etc, or is Rails really clever enough to work all this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you said, cooking_venues_dining_venues is the name of the join table. After creating this table with cooking_venue_id and dining_venue_id field you need to define has_and_belongs_to_many association in both model.

```
class CookingVenue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :dining_venues       # foreign keys in the join table
end
class DiningVenue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :cooking_venues    # foreign keys in the join table
end
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt responses.  Having come this far I'm now struggling with how to add entries into the join table.  Say I have an existing cooking_venue [id: 3, desc: 'Kitchen A'] and an existing dining_venue [id: 5, desc: 'Nice Eatery'.  I seem to have a mental block on how to match these 2 up in the Join table.  Lots of stuff on how to create the join table but not much on how to create the entry itself.  Probably so simple that it doesn't need explaining ..... except to me.

Comment: To answer my own second query this is what I've come up with.  In CookingVenue_Controller I can do : c=CookingVenue.find(3) d=DiningVenue.find(5)  c.dining_venues << d.  That creates the correct entry in the table.  My question now changes to : is this the correct 'Rails' way of doing it or is there something more elegant?

Comment: yes, << operator is the right way. However, if you want to create object when adding you can use c.dining_venues.create({:attribute_name => 'attribute value' })

Comment: My only concern with the way I've done it is that there are 2 hits on the database to find the 2 objects first, only to then insert a 3rd entry simply consisting of the ids of the 2 objects, which I had from the start.  I'm thinking it may be more efficient to simply use an sql insert statement directly on the join table.  Not 'Rails' but certainly more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Yup. You just name the join table in alpha order like you have done and you should be good to go.